# Make column rows the same value with matching value of another column when condition is met

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, replace, matching

I have a dataframe like below

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': ['A', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'D'],
                   'col2': [1,0,1,0,0,1]})
```

| col1 | col2 |
| --- | --- |
| A | 1 |
| A | 0 |
| B | 1 |
| C | 0 |
| D | 0 |
| D | 1 |

If there's one row from col2 = 1, I want to make all col2 rows = 1 for the same value col1 value. The table I'd want is as below:

| col1 | col2 |
| --- | --- |
| A | 1 |
| A | 1 |
| B | 1 |
| C | 0 |
| D | 1 |
| D | 1 |

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you only have 0 and 1 in the column, you can use `groupby` `transform`:

```
df['col2'] = df.col2.groupby(df.col1).transform('max')

df
  col1  col2
0    A     1
1    A     1
2    B     1
3    C     0
4    D     1
5    D     1
```

In general you can pass a lambda to return 1 if any value is 1:

```
df['col2'] = df.col2.groupby(df.col1).transform(lambda g: 1 if (g == 1).any() else g)

df    
  col1  col2
0    A     1
1    A     1
2    B     1
3    C     0
4    D     1
5    D     1
```

Comment: Unfortunately I more than 0 and 1 and also text

Comment: Updated with a general solution.

Comment: This works great! Thanks a lot!

Comment: You're welcome :)

Answer (score 3):

You can chunk it in two steps:

Get the rows where col2 is 1:

```py
filters = df.loc[df.col2.eq(1), 'col1']
```

Assign the new values to rows, where col1 is in `filters`:

```py
df.loc[df.col1.isin(filters), 'col2'] = 1

df
 
  col1  col2
0    A     1
1    A     1
2    B     1
3    C     0
4    D     1
5    D     1
```